# Python requests, CSV, Sha256 and BOM

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, byte-order-mark

I am gathering a set of CSVs for athletes using Requests and Python 2.7.

These files are being generated by MSFT Report Server and come through as iso-8859-1, says Requests.

Because I'm dealing with thousands every night, I want to sha256 the files and compare to the previous hash for the athlete.  If the hash matches, I won't bother saving the file to disk.  These files are small -- biggest is about 6K -- so no chunking / streaming issues.

sha256 is failing, however, because of a pesky BOM with these files.  I've looked at 10 different "solutions" here and cannot find one that will pull the BOM out through decode.encode so that I can do my sha256.

One workaround, that I may have to revert to, is that I can write the file to disk and then sha256 it there.  But that seems really bad form.

If I can strip out the BOM at the start, I'll have a process that works with sha256 and saves me from dealing with superfluous files.

I *think* the problem could be that I'm ostensibly trying string operations on what is a file object.  But since the object is still a u"/... hex stream, I thought these ops would work...

Here are the details:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://66.73.188.164/ReportServer?%2fCPTC%2fWomens1stHalfDetail&Team=&player=17424&rs:Format=CSV')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.raw
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x18afb70>
>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
>>> print r.headers['content-type']
text/plain
>>> r.text[0]
u'\xff'
```

First attempt to convert fails to decode using the indicated encoding type!

```
>>> z = r.text
>>> z.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And in fact, the "type" of z is now different than expected, perhaps because of sys (mac; utf8)?

```
>>> type(z)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> z[0]
u'\xff'
>>> z[0:5]
u'\xff\xfem\x00a'
```

Various attempts to decode and encode have failed me; here is one of many such attempts.

```
>>> z.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 22, in decode
(output, consumed) = codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm sure the answer is a one-liner; I'm just not seeing it.  Any guidance most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try omiting BOM by encoding only the rest of the file to get sha256? As in:

```
z = r.text[2:]
z.decode ...
```

The same logic would have to apply to the hashes of files already stored on the disk, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Very close -- and you solved it.  Update your answer to say z = r.text[2:] because the BOM is two bytes and I'll give you the answer / up vote with my thanks!!  See this:   >>> r.text[0]
u'\xff'
>>> r.text[1]
u'\xfe'
>>> r.text[2]
u'm'

Comment: @Todd Curry I'm glad it helped. Edit applied :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be using `r.content`, e.g.,

```
r.content.decode('utf8')
```

Alternatively you can also override `r.encoding` doing

```
r.encoding = 'utf8'
```

And then you can use `r.text` without having to worry.

Comment: Wish this worked.  Try for yourself; let me know if you see something different.  >>> r.content.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Looking at the response, why are you trying to convert this to UTF8? It looks like a fairly random set of bytes. Further `r.content[2:].decode('utf8')` doesn't raise an exception but I'm not sure it does what you want either. That said, if you ever port this code to Python 3, the answer you've accepted will be 100% wrong. `r.text` is already unicode and has no `decode` method on Python 3. The only way to do it would be to use `r.content.`

Comment: Read the OP - I'm trying to get rid of the BOM.  Conversion from Latin-1 to UTF-8 *should* take care of that, but was a method and not the goal -- and a method that didn't work.   I said in OP that I was using Python 2.7 Thanks.

Comment: `r.content.decode('utf-8-sig')` works for utf-8 with BOM.

Comment: based on @SerkanYilmaz advice I forced encoding to 'utf-8-sig' and r.json() worked fine for me.